# Use if (conditional statement) within group_by()

Tags: r

**Sample Data**

```r
df <- data.frame(
  cid = c(1,2,3,3,3,3,3),
  week_num = c(1,2,1,13,14,46,47)
)
```

Now I have a data frame of several columns, which contains id, number of weeks, ...
And I want to compare the number of weeks within each id and output the consecutive week.

The problem is, if I want to select out the specific rows with at least 2 consecutive weeks within a specific id, how should I implement the conditional statement within group_by(id)?

Now my idea is to use group_modify() or group_map()

Comment: Could you clarify what the output should be for your example?

Comment: Next time please provide the input in reproducible form. Everyone had to retype it.

Comment: The input now seems entirely missing  in the question.  I have retyped it at the end of my answer from the original image before the question was edited removing the input entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within cid the expression week_num - 1:n() will transform consecutive sequences into constant values so we can group by cid and that expression and extract all those with more than one row.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  group_by(cid) %>%
  group_by(w = week_num -  1:n(), .add = TRUE) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-w)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
    cid week_num
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     3       13
2     3       14
3     3       46
4     3       47
```

### Note

The input was originally provided in an image in the question but after an edit seems to be missing. At any rate the input in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
DF <- data.frame(cid = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  week_num = c(1, 2, 1, 13, 14, 46, 47))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
df[duplicated(df$cid), ]
```

```
output:
    cid week_num
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     3       13
2     3       14
3     3       46
4     3       47
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(cid = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), week_num = c(1, 
2, 1, 13, 14, 46, 47)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: That will show all but the first row in any cid but the question is asking only to show rows which are part of a sequence.  For example, change 13 to 5 and it shows rows with 5 and 14 but those should no longer be shown since they are no longer part of a sequence.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for clarification!